# PowerPoint get text from table cell

Tags: objective-c, scripting, powerpoint

I am trying to get the text from a table cell on a PowerPoint slide using scripting in Objective C.

I have no problem doing this in AppleScript:

```
set hasTable to has table of aShape

if hasTable then
   -- if table, get text from first cell
   set numRows to number of rows of aShape
   set numCols to number of columns of aShape

   set aTable to table object of aShape
   set firstCell to first cell of first row of aTable
   set aTextFrame to text frame of shape of firstCell
   set hasText to has text of aTextFrame
   if hasText then
      set theText to content of text range of aTextFrame
   end if
end if
```

However, what appears to be the equivalent in Objective C doesn't seem to work:

```
// if table present, get text from first cell
if( shape.hasTable )
{
   PowerPointShapeTable *shapeTable = (PowerPointShapeTable *)shape.get;

   NSLog(@"Shape has %ld x %ld table", shapeTable.numberOfRows, shapeTable.numberOfColumns);

   PowerPointTable *table = shapeTable.tableObject;

   NSLog(@"Table has %ld rows and %ld columns and orientation %u", table.rows.count, table.columns.count, table.tableDirection);

   PowerPointCell *cell = [table getCellFromRow:0 column:0];
   PowerPointShape *cellShape = cell.shape;

   PowerPointTextFrame *textFrame = cellShape.textFrame;
   if( textFrame.hasText )
   {
      NSLog(@"First cell is %@", textFrame.textRange.content);
   }
}
```

The numberOfRows and numberOfColumns properties of the ShapeTable aways return 0 (zero), and the rows and columns properties of the Table object are of of zero size.  On the off chance that the rows and columns arrays were broken somehow I tried the direct access method.  That didn't work either.

Has anyone got this to work?
Thanks.

OSX 10.9 (Mavericks), 
Xcode 5.0.1, 
Microsoft PowerPoint 2011

Comment: Did you try to run your applescript using NSAppleScript class and get your result back to an NSString ?

Comment: Yes I did that to get around the problem.  It is considerably less convenient than using the scripting interface directly.